# What is ip address 0.0.0.0

Tags: ip-address

I've been looking at the socket information in proc/net/tcp and I see a lot of the home connections (127.0.0.1) with a remote address of 0.0.0.0.  I was just wondering if a blank address like that had a use or name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means they are not bound to any particular *remote* address. This is most common with TCP listening sockets, and it means they will accept in inbound connection regardless of its source IP address.

Answer (score 3):

In that context, it basically means that there is no internet connection.

For the nitty-gritty, check out [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1).